# Xcode 6 Core Data Regenerating Subclasses

Tags: core-data, xcode6

Using Xcode 6 beta 4 Core Data, how do you regenerate the subclasses if you want to add/remove an Attribute?

For example, I create a new entity and add a few attributes then go to Editor > CreateNSManagedObjectSubclass.., it works the first time and creates the entity as a .swift file, but then if I go and add a new entity and try to regenerate the subclasses by choosing the same option in the editor menu it doesn't overwrite the .swift file with the new entity. This used to work for me in Xcode 5.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or what is the correct way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode won't silently overwrite your file. This is a feature, not a bug, because you will not inadvertently lose custom code in those classes.

If you want to replace the file, delete it first. The class generation will then work as expected.

Comment: Thanks, Mundi. Is that different from previous versions of Xcode? I thought that in the past the files would be overwritten but it didn't matter because if you wanted to add functionality to the classes then you would use categories. Is that not the same in Xcode 6 with Swift?

Comment: Correct, in my experience (i.e., without installing and checking old Xcode versions) this is new behavior. Maybe it is a bug in the sense that it silently fails, which might be unexpected.

Comment: +1. I am experiencing the same also. Previous versions of Xcode all silently replaced the modified files. It is true that this "feature/bug" becomes handy for not inadvertently losing custom code like @Mundi stated.

Comment: I think it's a Xcode 6 bug. Deleting and regenerating works as a temporary solution